# jquery change img attribute name without loosing atribute values

Tags: jquery

### Background

I generate dynamic php gallery in which it is possible to drag images by using jquery UI.

All images has option to be cropped.

Image that are listed first in a gallery are the "title image" of the gallery and have a different crapping ratio as non "title images".

### Problem

I echo out all images with attribute `'ondblclick="open_original=(21, 153)"'`.
I need to figure out how i can change `open_original` to `open_original_main` only for the first images of the gallery so they can have different cropping ratio.

If I use `.attr()` then i lose all my attribute values and i cant get them back. Is there any way to just replace their function names?

My jquery for this problem so far:

```
$(".galOf .gallery_nav:first-child .img_thumb img").ready(function(){
    $(this.ondblclick).replace("open_original","open_original_main");
});
```

I know `.replace()` is not a function, just read info....

Comment: what isnt working with attr()? can you show us the code you tried using attr()?  Also give us an example of the entire div elemeent from < to > before and after so we can see specifically hwo you want it changed.

Comment: Who says if you use `.attr()`, you'd loose all your attribute values? Where have you read that?

Comment: there is no way i can get attribute values back if i use attr(). as far as i know i just can delete attribute with removeAttr() and create new with attr() but i cant "save" my values in attribute

Comment: No, you are wrong. You can use `$('#myimg').attr('title', 'new title');` to change the `title` attribute.

Comment: `.attr` like `.val` is both a `getter` *and* a `setter`. They could be used to read the current value, or to assign a new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
var attrName = $('#image:first').attr("ondblclick");

var newAttrName = attrName.replace("open_original","open_original_main");

$('#image:first').attr("ondblclick", newAttrName );
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be easier to change the click event handler in php and echo the correct one rather than changing it with jquery. Just use a counter or something like it and if the counter is equal to its initial state then use "open_original_main", else use "open_original".

Comment: yes, but... like i sad, i can drag images. i take image from middle and drag it to the beginning of gallery - that image needs to have "open_original_main" function in "ondblclick" attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".galOf .gallery_nav:first-child .img_thumb img").ready(function(){
  var val = $(this).attr("ondblclick"); // copy attribute value
  val = val.replace("open_original","open_original_main"); //replace
  $(this).attr("ondblclick",val); // set attribute value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Form what you say in the comments, it seems you want to do different things based on the position of the thumbnail. It also seems most of the code in the two functions are identical. You do not need to repeat all the code to a new function then. Here is what you can do:

```
function open_img() {
  // is this the first image?
  var isFirst = $(this) == $('.galOf .gallery_nav:first-child .img_thumb img');

  if(isFirst) open_original(100, 100);
  else open_original (21, 153);
}
```